# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)

Tags: php, syntax, unset

I am using simple php unset() function to remove and index of array but it's showing the following error:

```php
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)
```

Here is my erroneous code:

```php
echo $totalArray = unset($linkExtHelp[0]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this, Reason for `unset($linkExtHelp[0])` assigning to the variable `echo $totalArray  =` 
You can't assign the `unset()` value to the variable, You can use to check before unset and after unset as like below. In other words,  `unset` does not have any return value, since `unset` is a void. Void -  does not provide a result value to its caller.

**Syntax:** void unset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

```
echo "Before unset: ".$linkExtHelp[0];
unset($linkExtHelp[0]);
$linkExtHelp = array_values($linkExtHelp);
echo "After unset: ".$linkExtHelp[0];
```

instead of

```
echo $totalArray  =     unset($linkExtHelp[0]);
```

Comment: Nit: `unset` *isn't* a function. A *real* [void] function would have resulted in a different error.

Comment: May i know what is the error in this code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d319d2506c52   i am getting same error like  ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET) in C:\wamp\www\voice_bank\playlist_action.php on line 11

Answer (score 10):

[`unset`](http://www.php.net/unset) does not return a value - it *cannot* be used meaningfully as an expression, even if such a production was accepted.

However, the *parse error* is caused because [`unset` is a keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) and a "special production": even though `unset` looks like a function, it is *not* a function<sup>1</sup>. As such, `unset` is only valid as a *statement*<sup>2</sup> per the language grammar.

The production can be found in [zend_language_parser.y](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y):

```
309 unticked_statement:
       |   ..
338    |   T_UNSET '(' unset_variables ')' ';'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The syntax is due to historical design choices, and arguably a mistake from a consistency viewpoint:

> Note: Because *[unset] is a language construct and not a function*, it cannot be called using variable functions.

<sup>2</sup> There is also "(unset) casting", but I'm ignoring that here.

Answer (score 1):

### Unset does not return anything, it is a keyword.

**I assume you want to re-index the array, you can use `array_values` to do this**

Try this:

```php
unset($linkExtHelp[0]);
$totalArray = array_values($linkExtHelp);
```

Comment: What does this add that the existing and accepted answers don't have?

Comment: @JasonAller The existing answer will leave the array missing a first value, my answer re-indexes (reassigns keys for the values)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign "unset". this is how I do.
you need to make a temp array.

```
 $totalArray  = $linkExtHelp; // assign it to a new array (so you can keep the original one )

 foreach ($totalArray  as $key => $value) {
 unset($totalArray  [$key]['save_day']); // if you need to remove all of 'save_day' value from multi array
 }
 var_dump($totalArray); // after unset
 var_dump($linkExtHelp); // the original array


 //echo $totalArray  =     unset($linkExtHelp[0]); // This is wrong. no echo
```

I hope it helps.